# Why was a time of war described as "good"?

Tags: poetry, ukrainian-language, taras-shevchenko, the-complete-kobzar

The poem *Ivan Pidkova* by Taras Shevchenko (in *The Complete Kobzar*) contains the following lines:

> There was an age - that trouble
> Pranced about Ukraine,
> Grief quaffed honeymead
> Like rebels in a tavern.
> There was a time
> When living in Ukraine was good...
> Let's recall it! Perhaps the
> Heart will rest a bit.

Why does the poem refer to a period of warfare as "good"? Or am I misunderstanding this line?

Comment: Maybe those times were different times. It's not clear to me that this "age" and this "time" are meant to occur simultaneously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand these lines, it is useful to also look at the poem's opening. I do not have a copy of *The Complete Kobzar*, so I will be using the version from *The Poetical Works of Taras Shevchenko: The Kobzar*, available from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/poeticalworksoft0000unse_c0m0), and so the translations may differ slightly.

The opening lines are:

> There was a time in our Ukraine 
> When cannon roared with glee 
> A time when Zaporozhian men 
> Excelled in mastery! 
> They lived as masters - freedom’s joy 
> And glory were their gain

Here Shevchenko is harking back to an idealised vision of Ukraine, before it was amalgamated into the Russian Empire. It was peopled by the Zaporozhian cossacks who led free and warlike lives. This cultural reference to Ukraine's romantic cossack past is common to many of Shevchenko's poems. John Panchuk, for example, remarked in *Shevchenko's Testament* that:

> For Shevchenko, Ukraine is the home of the Zaporozhian Kozaks, whose
> valor and exploits in countless struggles were the bulwark for over
> two centuries of individual and political freedom of the people, whose
> glory and fame were preserved in songs and ballads of the wandering
> minstrels, the *kobzars* of Ukraine.

The subject of the poem, [Ivan Pidkova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Pidkova), was a prominent leader of the Ukrainian cossacks, fighting against domination by the Ottoman empire, possibly even leading a raid on Constantinople itself. This "happy time" of martial prowess ended, however, and Shevchenko continues:

> All that has passed, and what is left 
> Is grave mounds on the plain

The "grave mounds" refer to the burial mounds where many of the cossacks were buried, and with them, symbolically, Ukrainian freedom. For that reason Shevchenko regarded them as sacred, and was appalled by the archeological expeditions that despoiled them (see for example his poem "The Great Mound" from 1845).

The lines quoted in the question echo the opening lines:

> There was a time when in Ukraine 
> Even distress would dance 
> And sorrow in a tavern drank 
> In honeyed brandy’s dance

In that happy past time, even the unpleasant aspects of life, distress and sorrow, were better than the way they appear in Shevchecnko's time. Although they are undesirable, they are nonetheless tolerable because they are being experienced by free people.

The verse ends with the lines:

> There was a time when life was good 
> In that Ukraine of ours... 
> Recall it then - perhaps the heart 
> May briefly bathe in flowers

which again calls to the reader to remember the golden era of Ukraine's past, and hold on to the hope that those days may come again.